# Ajax xhr producing error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use the exact same code as this for uploading images and showing progress, on this occasion though the only change is uploading audio files yet the xhr simply halts and produces this error:

```
[object Object]an error occurred
```

html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="audioForm">
    <p>Click browse to choose the audio file(mp3) from your PC (Maximum file size is 5mb)</p>
    <input type="file" name="audio" value="" class="input-xlarge required"><br />
    <label for="song_title">Song Title</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="act_id" value="<?=$act_id?>">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="song_title" name="song_title">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload Images" id="uploadAudio" />
</form>

<div id="progress" style="display:none;">
    <progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>
<div id="response" style="display:none;"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '#uploadAudio', function(){

        var form = new FormData($('#audioForm')[0]);
        $('#progress').fadeIn();

        // Make the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/actions/addAudio.php?act_id=<?=$act_id?>',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progress, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (res) {
                $('#progress').hide();
                $('#response').show();
                $('#response').html(res);
                $("#audioDisplay").load('/ajax/display/audioDisplay.php?act_id=<?=$act_id?>');
            },
            error: function(res){
                $('#progress').hide();
                $('#response').show();
                $('#response').html(res + 'an error occurred');
            },
            data: form,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
         });
});
```

Anything obvious?

New error function:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    $('#response').html('textStatus: ' + textStatus + '<br>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
},
```

Which gives this error:

```
textStatus: error
errorThrown: TypeError: Argument 2 of EventTarget.addEventListener does not implement interface EventListener.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the complete form of the error function:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   ...
}
```

*textStatus* and *errorThrown* will provide you with more information about the nature of the error.

Comment: Thanks, how do i then display them?

Comment: Using your code you could do something like: $('#response').html('textStatus: ' + textStatus + '<br>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);

Comment: This means that your progress object does not implement the Event listener interface.

You can find more information on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Comment: Yeah I saw that - but, I use exactly the same code on a different page of the same site and it works perfectly? That's what I can't understand

Comment: I suggest that you use a javascript debugger (there is one in chrome or you can use FireFox with FireBug) to analyze the code of your working page and compare it to the one that does not work. I suspect that your other page includes some other javascript that initializes the progress object that your new page does not include.